# Interpretation of Relative Difference in Differences Results with Relative Units

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference

I am writing a paper using a difference-in-differences analysis.  My control and treatment groups are groups of 7 or 6 states that either do not or do undergo a certain policy.  I ran my difference-in-differences regression and ended up with the equation [image]

I am confused on the interpretation of my results for the actual DID coefficient of .022.  This is because average spending is measured relative to the month of January 2020.  Any help on the interpretation of this coefficient would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. So the "outcome" is average spending, by month, but *relative to* the month of January? Is January 2020 the first observation period?

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, January 13, 2020 is where the data on spending begin.  Apologies, I should have specified that this is daily data, and it is measured "relative to January 4-31, 2020 (as these are the first four complete weeks in 2020) calculated as a 7 day moving average."

Comment: I'll give it a try. I hope I haven't misunderstood your variables; they were not immediately clear to me. Since both variables are in levels, then ∆y=β∆x. So your policy increases the average spending of 0.22 units (if in thousands, it's a 220 increase). If you have daily data capturing a weekly average, then it's a 0.22 increase in the weekly average itself. I wouldn't worry about all measures being relative to Jan 13, since that shuold be equivalent to setting a common baseline.